# Code is giving me an infinite recursion error

Tags: python, function

I have a program that is meant to choose a random Media type, and then a random Genre, but for some reason, as soon as the program gets to the genre function, it enters an infinite loop. I don't see why it is giving me a recursion error, as I do not have any looping functionality added in.

```py
def genre(mediumType):

    mediumType = genre(mediumType)

    if mediumType == 'Game':
        genreType = random.choice(['Fantasy','Sci-Fi','Action','Horror','Indie','Puzzle','RPG','JRPG','Strategy','Shooter','Open World'])
        return genreType
    elif mediumType == 'Book':
        genreType = random.choice(['Fiction','Non-Fiction','Thriller','Mystery','Poetry','Sci-Fi','Fantasy'])
        return genreType
    elif mediumType == 'Anime':
        genreType = random.choice(['Feel Good','Thriller','Isekai','Shounen','Seinen','Sci-Fi','Comedy',])
        return genreType
    elif mediumType == 'TV':
        genreType = random.choice(['Horror','Drama','Comedy','Sci-Fi'])
        return genreType
    elif mediumType == 'Movie':
        genreType = random.choice(['Sci-Fi','Fantasy','Comedy','Superhero','Horror'])
        return genreType


def medium():

    medium = random.choice(['game','book','anime','tv','movie'])

    # Games
    if medium == 'game':
        genreType = genre('Game')
        result = "Play a(n) " + genreType + " game\n"
        return result

    # Books
    elif medium == 'book':
        genreType = genre('Book')
        result = "Read a " + genreType + " book\n"
        return result

    # Anime
    elif medium == 'anime':
        genreType = genre('Anime')
        result = "Watch a(n) " + genreType + " anime\n"
        return result

    # TV Shows
    elif medium == 'tv':
        genreType = genre('TV')
        result = "Watch a " + genreType + " TV Show\n"
        return result

    # Movies
    elif medium == 'movie':
        genreType = genre('Movie')
        result = "Watch a " + genreType + " movie\n"
        return result
```

Comment: You're calling `genre()` again at line 2. It is behaving as you're instructing it to. It never gets out of the calling loop.

Comment: your first line of your `genre` function is `mediumType = genre(mediumType)` which calls the function again so of course it will be infintie recursion

Comment: You probably meant to call `medium()` there instead of `genre()`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to 
`mediumType = genre(mediumType)` function which is recursively calling other function.
Comment out this line in order to fix the issue.